# group by, remove duplicates, keep last in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a way to remove duplicates in player (but keep the last instance) of each group in pos. The dataframe looks like this:

```
id  pos  player  xB
1   1.0  406042  0.05
2   1.0  406041  0.05
3   2.0  406041  0.1
4   2.0  406042  0.1
5   2.0  406041  0.1
6   3.0  406041  0.5
7   3.0  406042  0.5
8   4.0  406043  0.05
9   4.0  406041  0.05
10  4.0  406043  0.05
11  4.0  406043  0.05
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
id  pos  player  xB
1   1.0  406042  0.05
2   1.0  406041  0.05
4   2.0  406042  0.1
5   2.0  406041  0.1
6   3.0  406041  0.5
7   3.0  406042  0.5
9   4.0  406041  0.05
11  4.0  406043  0.05
```

Hopefully someone can help me, and let me know if I need to clarify anything :)

Comment: Use `df.drop_duplicates(['pos','player'], keep='last')`

Comment: Perfect - thank you :)